# Как остановить цикл с selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, parse

У меня есть цикл в котором выполняются действия с selenium.

```
while loopflag:
    driver.get(link)
    element = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "annonces_entry_link")
    if ads_reg.lower() == "нет":
         print("net")
    else:
         driver.quit()
         loopflag = False
```

После прохождения условия цикл останавливается, а селениум продолжает работать и через несколько секунд выдает такую ошибку

```
raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=50081): Max retries exceeded with url: /session/2979bc01b96dcad71567dd73a8aac239/element (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x0000021E80BB9FF0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] Подключение не установлено, т.к. конечный компьютер отверг запрос на подключение'))
```

Как сделать чтобы селениум тоже остановил свою работу и вышел из программы?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй, если это допустимо по логике программы, закрывать окно сразу после того, как закончишь работать с ним driver.close()

Answer (score 0):

в конце работы с драйвером driver.quit()

Comment: А разве `driver.quit()` не написан в изначальном коде в вопросе?